# How do I correctly access a variable from a Class in another file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to make a UI for a future project using `tkinter`. However, I'm having a lot of trouble setting up some basic OOP concepts.

I have two files, `main.py` and `pressed.py`, I'm trying to write a function for a button press in `pressed.py` but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get access to variables in `main.py`

Here's the error I'm currently running into:

```
Class 'UI' has no 'py_entry' member
```

I've tried using a lot of other Stack Overflow posts for reference, but none of them has worked.

## main.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os
import geocoder

from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

import pressed

# Paths
assets_path = "./assets/"

class UI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Set window title
        parent.title("geo-location-data")

        # Set window geometry
        parent.geometry("800x600")

        # Address entry label
        py_label = tk.Label(parent, text="Emter an addres:", font=("Helvetica", 12))
        py_label.place(x=0, y=0)

        # Address entry field
        py_entry = tk.Entry(parent, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        py_entry.place(x=130, y=2)

        # Open button_normal.png
        button_normal_img = Image.open(assets_path + "button_normal.png")

        # Resize button_normal.png
        button_normal_img_resize = button_normal_img.resize((16, 16), Image.BILINEAR)
        button_normal_img_resize_format = "resized_button_normal" + ".png"

        # Set path
        path_for_button_normal = os.path.join(assets_path, button_normal_img_resize_format)

        # Save to path
        button_normal_img_resize.save(path_for_button_normal)

        # Open saved image
        button_normal_img_r_open = Image.open(assets_path + "resized_button_normal.png")
        button_normal_img_r_open = ImageTk.PhotoImage(button_normal_img_r_open)

        #def button_pressed(self):
            # If address entry field is blank
            #if(py_entry.index("end") == 0):
                #messagebox.showerror("Error", "Entry field was left blank.")
                #return self
            #else:
                #print("test")
                #return self

        # Pressed

        # ADD COMMAND #
        py_button = tk.Button(parent, font=("Helvetica", 12), width=16, height=16, image=button_normal_img_r_open)
        py_button.place(x=320, y=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    UI(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

## pressed.py

```py
from sample import main

from tkinter import messagebox

class Pressed(main.UI):
    def __init__(self):
        def button_press(self):
            # This is where I'm getting the error
            if (main.UI.):
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Address entry field was left blank.")
                return self
            else:
                print("Button pressed!")
                return self
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are declaring local variables inside the class which are only accessible from within the `__init__()` function. Python has a way to create class variables by either declaring them inside the class (outside of a method) or by calling `self.variable_name`. You then can access that variable by calling `self.variable_name` every place inside the class.
`self` is a reference to the current instance of your class.

For your example the way you probably want to could declare the variable is with the `self` keyword:

```
class UI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.py_entry = tk.Entry(parent, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.py_entry.place(x=130, y=2)
```

You should then be able to access the `py_entry` field after creating an instance of the `UI` class (calling `UI()`).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I tried adding self to the variable but I'm still unable to access it, it gives me the same error. Is there anything I need to change in the class or function I wrote in pressed.py?

Comment: I am not really sure. Your code structure is somewhat hard to follow since you have so much code unrelated to the issue. I also don't know how you're using the pressed function since that isn't shown or how you are calling it. Make sure that you create an instance of the UI class. Unless it's a static class you can't just access its fields.

Comment: That worked, I just instantiated it wrong at first. Thanks!